# Error excuting correct native query with pageable, regular expression

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm migrating a project from Spring Boot 2.7.14 to 3.1.2. I have the following pageable, native query:

```
@Query(value = "select * from user where (is_external_user is false) " +
            " AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :linerlist)) " +
            " AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :idlist)) " +
            " AND (first_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :namelist) OR last_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :namelist)) ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserOneSystemTable> findCustomAllByUserIdListAndUserNameList(@Param("linerlist") List<String> linerList,
                                                                      @Param("idlist") List<String> userIdList,
                                                                      @Param("namelist") List<String> userNameList,
                                                                      Pageable pageable);
```

Calling this function results under Spring Boot 3.1.x in a DataIntegrityViolationException:

```
SQL Error: 1241, SQLState: 21000
(conn=3598) Operand should contain 1 column(s)
[User (for App)][Get User (One System)] Error: CAUSE         = JDBC exception executing SQL [select * from user where (is_external_user is false)  AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?,?)))  AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)))  AND (first_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)) OR last_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)))  order by user_id asc limit ?]; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]
STACK TRACE   = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select * from user where (is_external_user is false)  AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?,?)))  AND (user_id REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)))  AND (first_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)) OR last_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', (?)))  order by user_id asc limit ?]; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]
```

Under Spring Boot 2.7.14 everything works as expected. I expect working generated sql code (as under Hibernate 5.6.x).